# Is there a case-insensitive collation in MySQL that also insensitive towards a string and its trimmed version?

Tags: mysql, case-insensitive

I know, there is a lot of case-insensitive collations (e.g. utf8_bin), but besides that, I need a collation that also treats a string as its trimmed version (let's call it "trim-insensitivity"), so it can't distinguish the following two strings: "abc" and "    aBc "

Answer (score 0):

try with collate utf8_general_ci

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/119bd9f/1

Comment: case-insensitivity + trim-insensitivity for this example means that my query should return all three records of docs, not just one:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e18947/1/0

Comment: IMHO In Sql the trim-insensitivity is done with like operator, if, by trim-insensity you mean: trim whitespaces from strings and then select the records, you have to treat those strings before the query. i.e. this is not what you need http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e18947/4

Comment: I know about LIKE operator, but I don't want to use it since it can't use indexes and eventually will work slow for large data. I thought maybe there is a collation that can be trim-insensitive too so I can develop a search by value (using = operator)

Comment: you need to change the point of view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182295/improve-performance-on-mysql-fulltext-search-query